# Change structure of Maven Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I would like to change the structure of our project. The project was created on custom archetype based on 3 modules and one parent pom. However, i do not continue like this stucture.

I am stucked how to replace the project like spring boot project structure.

Is there any converting tool or maven project something to change the stucture.

Because more than 100 projects has ben built like this structure.

Many thanks

Comment: Do one by hand--there's no way to know what's entailed in "changing the structure" with the information provided. If you're moving from/to well-defined structures there will be a series of discrete steps, e.g., moving files, changing XML/property values, renaming packages, etc. Most of that can be done w/ content-aware search-and-replace. Automate the steps taken.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am stucked how to replace the project like spring boot project structure.`?  And what exactly is the problem? And why do you think the "new" structure would be better?